# How to filter an Array and Replace some values out of it

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

For Example I have this Array:

```
 const mainArray = [
   {name: 'Tom', age: 33, status: 0 }, 
   {name: 'James', age: 23, status: 0}, 
   {name: 'Bryan', age: 34, status:1 }  
 ]
```

and then I have this 2nd Array

```
 const toUpdateStatus = ['Tom', 'James']
```

the expected value of the Array should be like this after merging the two

```
   const finalValue = [
       {name: 'Tom', age: 33, status: 1 }, 
       {name: 'James', age: 23, status: 1}, 
       {name: 'Bryan', age: 34, status:0 }  
     ]
```

what I have tried so far is this

```
const result = toUpdateStatus.map((checked) => mainArray.filter((val) => val.name.includes(checked)));
```

but to no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return an object from the `.map` immediately, with a `status` property of whether the name is included in the `toUpdateStatus`, converted to a number:

```js
const mainArray = [
 {name: 'Tom', age: 33, status: 0 }, 
 {name: 'James', age: 23, status: 0}, 
 {name: 'Bryan', age: 34, status:1 }  
] 

const toUpdateStatus = ['Tom', 'James'];

const output = mainArray.map(({ name, age }) => ({
  name,
  age,
  status: Number(toUpdateStatus.includes(name))
}));
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can quickly make a Map of the `toUpdateStatus` using the names as values and status as 1. Then array map the original and get() status from the lookup Map or set as zero if not existing.

This way neither array gets iterated more than once.

```js
const mainArray = [{name: 'Tom', age: 33, status: 0 }, {name: 'James', age: 23, status: 0}, {name: 'Bryan', age: 34, status: 1 }] ;
const toUpdateStatus = ['Tom', 'James'];

const stats = new Map(toUpdateStatus.map(name => [name, 1]));
const res = mainArray.map(el => ({...el, status: stats.get(el.name) || 0}))

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to some other answers, but makes no assumptions about the fields in your objects except that they have a `name` property:

```js
const updateStatus = (main, names) => main .map (
  ({name, ...o}) => ({name, ...o, status: Number(names .includes (name))})
)

const mainArray = [{name: 'Tom', age: 33, status: 0 }, {name: 'James', age: 23, status: 0}, {name: 'Bryan', age: 34, status: 1 }] 
const toUpdateStatus = ['Tom', 'James'] 

console .log (updateStatus (mainArray, toUpdateStatus))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {min-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Map-index for main array:

```
var map = {};
mainArray.forEach(v=>map[v.name] = v);
//OR
var map = mainArray.reduce((s,v)=>(s[v.name] = v, s), {});
```

2. Reset records:

```
mainArray.forEach(v=>v.status = 0);
```

3. Update records:

```
toUpdateStatus.forEach(v=>map[v].status = 1);
```